# How do I access a type from a C++/CLI dll in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, dll, c++-cli

I created a C++/CLI dll with the below code:

```
#pragma once

#include "msg.h" //msg_t is a struct defined here

using namespace System;

namespace myCLRDll 
{

    typedef msg_t my_msg_t;

    public ref class Class1
    {
    };
}
```

build the library, add the reference to my C# application and the `using myCLRDll;` directive but when I went to use the `my_msg_t` I get an undefined identifier error:

> The type or namespace name 'my_msg_t' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why this type isn't visible? Do I need to do any kind of "type export"? is there any workaround?

Comment: Class1 will be visible, but not typedefs - there is no mechanism to expose typedefs to C# or any other .NET language. That is, the only types that C# can see are C++/CLI managed types.

Comment: Is there even any way to expose to C# a struct or class defined in native C++ via C++/CLI?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: I hadn't see you edit. Post it as answer so I can mark as accepted. Thanks

Comment: You would need to wrap `msg_t` in a `public ref class` (the CLR class would contain and forward/marshal data to/from the `msg_t` type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons for C# not seeing the typedef:

1. C# can only see managed types from your C++/CLI library. There is no mechanism to allow C# to access unmanaged types directly.
2. The 'typedef' statement in a C++/CLI library is never available to another .NET application. It is only available within the C++/CLI library where it is in scope.